calcular o preço e quantidade de um input number e exibir resultado em tempo real
Bom Dia,
Estou com um problema talvez simples de resolver mas estou meio enferrujada,
Preciso multiplicar o valor do input(preço) com o input-number(quantidade) e jogar o resultado em outro campo input(total) em tempo real. Ou seja preciso calcular o valor de preço e quantidade quando clicasse no input-number para aumentar a quantidade ele já ia realizando a conta e jogava no campo total em tempo real.
Meu código está assim:
<script>
 

    function calcular(){
        var valor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('preco').value, 10);
        var valor2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantidade').value, 10);
    
    
        document.getElementById('total').value = num1 + num2;
    }

  </script>

os campos:
 <input type="text" id="preco" name="preco" class="form-control" placeholder="Preco" value="" required onkeyup="calcular()">
                  
  <input type="number" name="quantidade" id="quantidade" class="form-control"  value="" placeholder="" min="0"  max="" onkeyup="calcular()">
                  
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" class="form-control" placeholder="">
              

Então o que eu queria era que ao clicar para aumentar a quantidade do produto no input-number, ele já realizasse a multiplicação e jogava o valor total no input total em tempo real.
os dados vem assim nos inputs:
       Preço   |    Quantidade  |    Total
     R$ 12,00  |       2     ^  |   R$ 24,00

imagem

Se no campo de preço vc digitar R$ 12,00 o parseInt não vai funcionar, porque ele não reconhece R$ como parte de um número válido. Então ou vc remove esses caracteres antes do parseInt, ou muda o input para receber apenas números.

só que esse R$ vem do banco de dados, e ele não esta aceitando o valor como 12,50 ele ignora a virgula e calcula direto

Como eu já disse, uma das opções é remover o "R$". E como o valor tem casas decimais, então não deveria ser parseInt e sim parseFloat. Mas como parseFloat só aceita o ponto (e não a vírgula) como separador decimal, tem que trocá-la também. Ou seja, algo como parseFloat(valueDoInput.replace('R$', '').replace(',', '.'))

Importante seguir as instruções já dadas na 1a vez que perguntou. Você pode corrigir os erros e, depois disso, se ainda tiver algum problema, pode editar AQUELA postagem melhorando, que ela entra numa revisão automaticamente (pode clicar em restaurar depois). Para evitar que os comentários fiquem espalhado nas duas postagens, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas pode ser usado na original depois da restauração.
